# after upgrade to 12.04 network manager doesn't work at all

Tags: 12.04, laptop, network-manager

I find in syslog some messages 
"network manager(PID) terminated with status 1"

If I try to run NetworkManager manually I get

"Failed to read classid fil: Object not found"

In 11.10 it was working with Cable with Wi-FI  and With 3G USB key

What would be the workaround considering that the notebook is unable to connect to any network?

Comment: What brand/model of laptop (netbook)? What is the network chip (brand/model), if known?